# how can I filter student with all details whose "active" value is "true"?

Tags: ios, swift

I want to filter all details(school, city, name, active) whose active value is true. I have stored value of key "details"

```
let details = jsonRes[RequestResponses.Keys.details.rawValue] as? Dictionary< String, Any>

    {
      "details": {
        "code": 235,
        "school": "sp school",
        "students": [
          { "name": "1student", "Active": false },
          { "name": "2student", "Active": true },
          { "name": "3student", "Active": true },
          { "name": "4student", "Active": false },
          { "name": "5student", "Active": false}
        ]
      }
    }
```

Expected Result

```
    [
      "details": {
        "code": 235,
        "school": "sp school",
        "students": [
          { "name": "2student", "Active": true },
          { "name": "3student", "Active": true }
        ]
      }
    ]
```

Comment: The school isn't tied to an `Active` value, and there is no city data in what you've shown.  Can you make it a little clearer what exactly you want the filtered data to look like?

Comment: Work with objects/structs, not with dictionaries, and everything will be much simpler.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `filter`

```
   if let details = jsonRes[RequestResponses.Keys.details.rawValue] as?  Dictionary< String, Any> ,
            let detailDic = details["details"] as? [String:Any],
            let students  = detailDic["students"]  as? [[String:Any]] {

            let activeStudents = students.filter { (item) -> Bool in
                guard let active  = item["Active"] as? Bool else {return false}
                return active
            }
            print(activeStudents)
        }
```

or you can use **shourthand**

```
     if let details = jsonRes[RequestResponses.Keys.details.rawValue] as?  Dictionary< String, Any> ,
                let detailDic = details["details"] as? [String:Any],
                let students  = detailDic["students"]  as? [[String:Any]] {

                let activeStudents = (details["students"] as? 
                [[String:Any]])?.filter{ $0["Active"] as? Bool == true}
                print(activeStudents)
            }
```

Comment: Or as a one-liner, `(details["students"] as? [[String:Any]])?.filter{ $0["Active"] as? Bool == true }`, though that doesn't account for the school and city data that they mentioned.

Comment: updated , i don't prefer using shourthand for new developers

Comment: @AbdelahadDarwish thank you so much for giving answer. it works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

You start realising the true elegance of Swift once you start turning this into regular objects using `Codable`. This will let you do things as in the Playground:

```
import Cocoa

let jsonData = """
    {
        "details": {
            "code": 235,
            "school": "sp school",
            "students": [
                { "name": "1student", "Active": false },
                { "name": "2student", "Active": true },
                { "name": "3student", "Active": true },
                { "name": "4student", "Active": false },
                { "name": "5student", "Active": false}
            ]
        }
    }
    """.data(using: .utf8)!

struct Student : Codable {
    let name: String
    let active: Bool

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case name
        case active = "Active"
    }
}

struct School : Codable {
    let code: Int
    let school: String
    let students: [Student]
}

struct Details: Codable {
    let details: School
}

do {
    let det = try JSONDecoder().decode(Details.self, from: jsonData)
    print(det)

    let activeStudents = det.details.students.filter({(student)->Bool in student.active})
    print(activeStudents)
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

This is obviously much easier to understand and Xcode can also support you much better during the process. The effort spent on the parser is minimal and easily recovered by the sheer elegance and clarity of the final filtering line.